# Expand absolute div to relative child auto width

Tags: html, css, html-lists

So, I've got a sub menu `ul` item, which I need to expand to the auto `width` of the widest child `li`, without specifying actual `width`. As of right now, child ul is taking the width of .mainlink  and text inside li items starts collapsing. I need it to be in one line and go beyond .mainlink width if necessary.

I've tried all the possible `display`s, but can't get it to work.

```css
.mainnav {
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}
ul.mainnav li {
  display: table-cell;
}
.subnav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
}
.menuitem {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainnav">
  <li class="mainlink"><a href="">Link 11</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mainlink">
    <a href="">Link 12</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li class="menuitem"><a href="">link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem"><a href="">link 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reset `padding` on `.subnav` because `ul` has `padding` by default

**UPDATE** (based on OP updated question)

use `display:inline-block` in `.mainnav > li`

---

```css
.mainnav {
  background:lightyellow;
  position:relative
}
ul.mainnav > li {
  display: inline-block;
  background:lightblue;
}
.subnav {
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  padding: 0;
  border: 5px solid green
}
.menuitem {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background: red
}
```

```html
<ul class="mainnav">
  <li class="mainlink"><a href=" ">Link 11</a></li>
   <li class="mainlink">
    <a href="">Link 12</a>
    <ul class="subnav">
      <li class="menuitem"><a href="">link 1</a>
      </li>
      <li class="menuitem"><a href="">link 2 long text</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: hm... it obviously works here, but not in my original code. edit: i think i see what could be the reason. let me edit the question.

Comment: that's typos because of i was using a simplified code here without all the coloring and font styles. The subnav is actually taking width of parent table-cell. So, i'm not sure if there is any way to go beyond that without js

Comment: what you are trying to achieve? Its quiet unclear now for me, you want the`sub-nav li`'s to be all display inline or one by one ? Because both my snippets achieved that filling the `.subnav ul` parent has you saw

Comment: Sorry about that. Takes a little to figure out the best way to ask this question. See updated question.

Comment: Same thing. Obviously works here, but not in my code. Going through styles trying to find what's different

Comment: live site and I'll help you,  its about CSS specificity, but this fixes,

Comment: @VicT, you didn't pay attention to my snippet, so line 200 - remove `width.100%` from `.headermenu div ul` and line 208  remove `position:relative` from `.headermenu div ul li`

Comment: you're welcome , next time try to include the actual code you are working on for a better assistance `:)`